# Need help to select a div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select by clicking  the 'C' from the `dropdown` and when I move over to the `C` element.

Its class gets change to `x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected` and when I use this code in code to click the element

```
drivefindElement(By.className("x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected")).click();
```

it throws an exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.IllegalLocatorException: Compound class names are not supported. 
Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results.
```

Could you please help me to get the way to click this element?

html code .. from Firebug

```
<--div id="xyz" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 253px; height: 105px;">

<--div class="x-combo-list-item" ext:qtip="">A<--/div>

<--div class="x-combo-list-item" ext:qtip="">B<--/div>

<--div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected" ext:qtip="">C<--/div>

<--div class="x-combo-list-item" ext:qtip="">D<--/div>

<--div class="x-combo-list-item" ext:qtip="">E<--/div>

<--/div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your selector to xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this error because of multiple elements on your web page having class name = 'x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected' .

You can also verify this by installing the [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) add on for firefox and trying out the xpath you are using in your code.

Try to locate the correct WebElement you are trying to click with the help of firepath. You can even get the XPath of your element on the page with the help of firebug by right clicking on the WebElement and copying the xpath.